# Ionic iOS header padding removal

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I am getting a problem in my ionic project.

I have seen it been mentioned before, but none of the solutions have worked including making it fullscreen etc. because I want to keep the statusbar onscreen. Can this actually be achieved?

[image: http://postimg.org/image/43ih51znz/]

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The header bar is pushed down causing it to look huge, I think it is due to previous ios versions. I want it to be normal sized just under the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fix. You have to use `ionic.Platform.fullScreen(true, true);` in your `$ionicPlatform.ready` function. And Add

`<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>` in your config.xml file.

Lastly Make sure that your **index.html** file has this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But this seems to just place it under the statusbar, I assume that <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/> is meant to prevent this however it isn't. Any idea why? I have the statusbar plugin installed.

Comment: So its not overlaying on status bar anymore? okay! thats what you wanted, and now the problem is that you want header bar to be of normal size. Correct?

Comment: The header is in line with the status bar, so the clock is overlapping the clock. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

@nickmcblain, it is an iOS-post7 issue. I fixed this by putting a blank spacer above my header, but that is not a great solution because as you scroll the header slides under the iOS system bar. I still have to fix my [demos](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html), but that issue is there. If you want, try the SplashScreen Demo ([github](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test)) to see how I fixed this.

The issue is that post-7 the system bar is now transparent. Sorry, I don't have a clean fix for you. Here is the [link that reported the problem](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/phonegap-and-cordova-with-ios-7/).